# Cannot find route when going directly by URL react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, router, vite

I have some routes

```
<Route path="/bany" exact>
      <Bany />
    </Route>,
    <Route path="/sklep" exact>
      <Sklep />
    </Route>,
    <Route path="/cooferujemy" exact>
      <CoOferujemy />
    </Route>,
    <Route path="/404" exact>
      <NotFound />
    </Route>,
    <Redirect to="/404" />,
```

Everything works just fine, when I'm just going to routes by clicking buttons, but when I want to go to route directly by URL I get the 404 route. There are my package.json dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@honkhonk/vite-plugin-svgr": "^1.1.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "^1.3.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "vite": "^2.4.4"
  }
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.